# problem with switching layouts on a virtual machine ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, keyboard-layout, hyper-v

I have a problem with switching layouts (english/russian) on a virtual machine under ubuntu 22.04 (Windows 10 Hyper-V). After a certain time (some hours) after launch, switching between keyboard layouts stops working, despite the fact that the layout indicators continue to change. But the layout itself always remains English. The only way to restore the switch is to reboot.

Comment: In principle, functionality is restored without a reboot if to make changes to settings->keyboard, for example, remove and add the Russian keyboard again